# Print a variable value in selenium Ide by passing the value to a function in .js file

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-ide

I'm new to java scripting, and I was experimenting with selenium IDE.

Function:

```
Selenium.prototype.doAlert=function(a)
{
    var b=parseInt(a)
    alert(+b);
}
```

Selenium IDE:

```
store 10 a 
  echo ${a}  
  alert a
```

The message getting displayed is NaN '...
Can some one help me out?

Comment: Javascript is not java, so please don't put the java tag on future javascript questions.

Comment: Do an `alert(a);` as the first thing you do in the `doAlert` and see what that shows.

Comment: @KevinNagurski:  If I do alert(a); it shows 'a' in alert box.. that's it. I want to print 10.. If I do  alert(+a) -- it is showing NaN

Comment: @LawrenceAiello: Sorry.. Will keep that in mind .